# SumIf exclusions using neighboring values

Tags: sumifs

I have an income spreadsheet that tracks biweekly pay. Some deductions only come out 2 times a month. Usually, 2 months per year have 3 biweekly checks. I need to sum up the deductions without the third check. I attempted this sumif formula to no avail. I've tried different variations of this formula to try to get just one aspect of the calculation to work.

These formulas are trying to test the first check of the month.

```
=SUMIF(B1:AA1,MONTH(B1)=MONTH(C1),B61:AA61)

=SUMIF(B1:AA1,MONTH(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN()))=MONTH(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN()+1)),B61:AA61)
```

Not sure if SumIf is the way to go with this. Lost!

Comment: Date 01/13/23 01/27/23 02/10/23 02/24/23 03/10/23 03/24/23 04/07/23 04/21/23 05/05/23 05/19/23 06/02/23 06/16/23 06/30/23 07/14/23 07/28/23 08/11/23 08/25/23 09/08/23 09/22/23 10/06/23 10/20/23 11/03/23 11/17/23 12/01/23 12/15/23 12/29/23

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant method, but I solved my issues with this:

```
=COUNT(filter(B1:1,NE(ARRAYFORMULA(B1:1),ARRAYFORMULA(D1:1)),B1:1<now()))
```

I was also trying to get a running balance on a loan I am paying off. Hence the NOW() in the filter.

Thanks